# Какую синтаксическую роль словосочетание "о присутствии Берты" играет в предложении?

Tags: синтаксис, управление, словосочетания

Они подозревали о присутствии Берты.

"Подозревали о присутствии" определила как сказуемое + дополнение (связь сильное управление).

Словосочетание **о присутствии Берты** видится в таком случае как дополнение + дополнение (связь так же сильное управление).

Верно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Они подозревали о присутствии Берты.***

Роль в предложении и  вид грамматической связи в словосочетании – это разные вещи.

1. **Вид грамматической связи в словосочетаниях:**

(1) ***Подозревать (о чём?) о присутствии*** – сильное глагольное управление предложным падежом, обязательное наличие зависимого слова определяется по словарю:
ПОДОЗРЕВАТЬ,  2. что, **о чём** или с придат. дополнит. Предполагать что-л., допускать возможность чего-л.; **догадываться о чём-л.**  П. о подделке, плагиате.

***Присутствие (кого?) Берты*** – сильное управление родительным падежом, обязательное наличие зависимого слова определяется по словарю:
ПРИСУТСТВИЕ,  ср. 1. Личное пребывание, нахождение в каком-л. месте в данный момент. Ваше п. нежелательно. Обнаружить, выдать своё п. чем-л. **Присутствие посторонних в зале.**

2. **Члены предложения:**

Подозревали (о чём?) о присутствии – падежная форма существительного в роли **дополнения.** О присутствии (чьём) Берты – падежная форма существительного в роли **несогласованного определения.**

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

1. Вопрос  «о присутствии **(кого?)** Берты»  определяет только **падеж**, но не синтаксическую роль в предложении. Здесь родительный падеж **субъекта (чьё),**  а не родительный падеж **объекта (кого?)**.
2. Значение **субъекта** определяется по соотносительному предложению с глаголом: **присутствие** Берты – Берта **присутствовала**.   Информация **о способе различения** несогласованного определения и дополнения взята из книги Кустовой Г.И. "Синтаксис современного русского языка" (Курс лекций для вузов, 2019 год).

Answer (score 4):

*Они подозревали о присутствии Берты.*

Подозревали (о чём?) о присутствии - дополнение

(О чьём присутствии?)-о присутствии Берты. На мой взгляд, это всё-таки несогласованное определение. Связь - сильное беспредложное управление.

Как отличить несогласованное определение от дополнения?

Несогласованное определение можно заменить согласованным (полка с книгами – книжная полка), может быть выражено предложно-падежной формой (банка из-под варенья), при преобразование в глагольное словосочетание становится обстоятельством (сон до утра – спать до утра).

Если при преобразовании в глагольное словосочетание можно поставить падежный вопрос, это дополнение (надежда на успех – надеяться на что? – на успех).   В роли дополнения выступают родительный отношения к производителю, владельцу, руководителю: автор повести, директор школы, а также родительный содержания: проверка исполнения, цель путешествия.

Все остальные значения родительного выступают в роли определения (платье мамы, человек крутого нрава).

Дополнением является дательный адресата: ответ товарищу (отвечать товарищу), помощь нуждающимся (помогать нуждающимся).

Попробуем заменить согласованным определением: присутствие Берты - Бертово присутствие - неказисто, но это ещё и редкое имя, а если бы было так: присутствие Ивана - Иваново присутствие - всё нормально. Так что  я бы сочла определением на основе управления.

Или бы указала двойное значение: несогласованное определение с дополнительным значением дополнения.